# Cannot convert between STR to DT-I8 in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssms

I'm having this problem when using data conversion
the source column looks like this

```
[dti]
4.55
14.55
20.10
```

and my destination column is INT in SSMS, my output column from the source which is JSON file is STR 50.
I tried DT-I4 and Float datatypes and still throwing an error, Is it because of the dot within the numbers?

> [Data Conversion [2]] Error: Data conversion failed while converting
> column "dti" (75) to column "Copy of dti" (29).  The conversion
> returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be
> converted because of a potential loss of data.".

Comment: Do you want the floating point/decimal values or not?

Comment: @billinkc Yes, I want to store it just the way I have it in the source, I need to do some aggregations on it, later on, that's why it's required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supplied values convert just fine to the number types I tried.

A more likely scenario is that you have non-numeric data in there.

Repro

Source query

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   values 
        (CAST('4.55' AS varchar(50)))
, ('14.44')
, ('20.10')
)D(dti);
```

Data Conversion and the execution results both in the screenshot

[image]

I would configure the data conversion task to funnel my error rows to an alternate location so you can inspect the values that fail to convert.